# How to get a list of all Quote sobjects using apex/soql

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api, describesobject, quote

It appears that [Quote](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm) is a SF SObject, yet the following code renders the following error:

```
[SELECT Id From Quote]
```

> sObject type 'Quote' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

The following code throws an NPE on the first line:

```
SObjectType objType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Quote');
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

So what is a Quote? How do a get a list of them?

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Can you provide us with more information?
Because query you post HAVE TO work.
Is it possible that it is used in context of user who can't see this object?

Comment: I have run this query in a dev org, and in a enterprise org of one of our customers. In the dev org, the query is run from an admin account. In the enterprise org, the query is being run via the rest api (with the full access and refresh token permissions). The api version is 29.0.

Comment: In both is returning error?
How about answer/question from @sfdc_ninja?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may seem simple and I'm sorry if I'm wrong, but I suspect you haven't enabled quotes for your org.  It is not enabled by default, you have to manually do this step to use quotes.

**Setup -> Customize -> Quotes -> Settings -> Enable Quotes**

[image]

Comment: That might be it. I'll look into that. (I am new to SF, so no answer is too basic. thank you)

Comment: Following those steps allowed me to run the following line of apex. List<SObject> items = [SELECT Id From Quote];

Thanks for your help. I will have to follow up with the customer to make sure they are talking about Quotes, and not some other SObject like Opportunity.

Comment: Awesome.  Glad to help  :)

Comment: Looks like my customer was referring to Opportunities when they said Quotes.

Comment: I figured as much.  Would have been odd if they were asking you query something they hadn't even activated  :)